# i am finding an intersection of 2 arrays

Tags: arrays

```
int[] nums1 = new int[]{1,2,2,1};
        int[] nums2 = new int[]{2,2};
        
        int n1 = nums1.length;
        int n2 = nums2.length;
        int min = (n1 > n2)?n2:n1;
        List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            if (min == n2){
                if (Arrays.asList(nums1).contains(nums2)){
                    ans.add(nums2[i]);
                }
            }
            else{
                if (Arrays.asList(nums2).contains(nums1)){
                    ans.add(nums1[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

finding intersection of two arrays and store it in list but list comes empty.

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you include a tag for the programming language you are using. [tag:arrays] isn't really useful.